# Clustering data with Python based on their correlation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science, correlation

I would like to cluster the following set of data in two clusters corresponding to each line ("\" and "/" ) of the "X". I was thinking that it could be done using the Pearson correlation coefficients as distance metric in Scikit-learn Agglomerative clustering as indicated here ([How to use Pearson Correlation as distance metric in Scikit-learn Agglomerative clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303217/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-as-distance-metric-in-scikit-learn-agglomerative)). But it doesn't seem to work.

**Plot of the raw data**

[image: Plot of the raw data]

```
Data:
-6.5955882 11.344538
-6.1911765 12.027311
-5.4191176 10.346639
-4.7573529 7.5105042
-2.9191176 7.7205882
-1.5955882 6.6176471
-2.9558824 6.039916
-1.1544118 3.9915966
-0.088235294 4.7794118
-0.088235294 2.8361345
0.53676471 -1.2079832
2.7794118 0
3.4044118 -4.3592437
5.2794118 -3.9915966
6.75 -8.5609244
7.4485294 -6.8802521
5.1691176 -5.7247899
-7.1470588 -2.8361345
-6.7058824 -1.2605042
-4.4264706 -1.1554622
-3.5073529 0.78781513
-0.86029412 0.31512605
-1.0808824 2.1533613
-2.8823529 -0.42016807
1.0514706 2.2584034
1.9338235 4.4117647
4.6544118 5.5147059
3.7352941 7.0378151
6.0147059 8.2457983
7.0808824 7.7205882
```

The code I've tried:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

nc=2
data = np.loadtxt("cross-data_2.dat")
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], s=100, cmap='viridis')

def pearson_affinity(M):
   return 1 - np.array([[pearsonr(a,b)[0] for a in M] for b in M])

hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=nc, affinity = pearson_affinity, linkage = 'average')
y_hc = hc.fit_predict(data)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(data[y_hc ==0,0], data[y_hc == 0,1], s=100, c='red')
plt.scatter(data[y_hc==1,0], data[y_hc == 1,1], s=100, c='black')

plt.show()
```

The results of the clustering:

[image: Plot of the clustered data]

Is there something wrong in the code or should I simply use another method?

Comment: Can you try principal component analysis on the data and then plot the data using the principal components. I get the feeling it will be much easier to cluster them then.

Comment: What is wrong is simple: your data is 2d, but for correlation measures you'd expect each point to be an entire *series* of points (say, 52 dimensional for 52 weeks). You don't want to use correlation of *points*, but if clusters. Try correlation clustering instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose yet another method for this, [Gaussian Mixture Models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html).

```py
X = (your data)
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2,
                      init_params='random',
                      n_init=5,
                      random_state=123)
y_pred = gmm.fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(*X.T, c=y_pred)
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty neat idea!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is pretty much what I needed. Just one more question: can you apply this method to multidimensional data (e.g., if we add a third column to the data)?

Comment: I think that should work as well. If you have very high-dimensional data, you could take a look into correlation clustering. Some time ago, I implemented [correlation partitioning clustering](https://github.com/VarIr/copac). You could give it a try.

Comment: Cool, I will have a look to it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I can propose a alternative method to achieve this. **Since, you are trying to cluster points along same angle, we can first transform data to polar (r-theta) coordinates and then use simple `KMeans` clustering**.

```
r = np.sqrt(x[:, 0]**2 + x[:, 1]**2)
theta = np.arctan(x[:, 1]/x[:, 0])
xr = np.vstack((r*np.sin(theta), r*np.cos(theta))).T

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(2)
xx = km.fit_predict(xr)

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=xx)
```

[image: clustered data]